# Using promises in javascript - only hitting the server once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fully understand the usage of promises and the benefits they give. I have an AJAX call that grabs a bunch of data from the server. Right now I do not have promises implemented and the code hits the server anytime the user changes a view (all using the same data, just the way it looks).

Here is the promise I am trying to add:

```
function feedData(arr){
     //data being initialized
    this.initData();
}

feedData.prototype = {
    constructor: feedData,
    getData:function(){
        return $.ajax({
           url: 'php/getData.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
                //data being sent over
           }
        });
    },
    initData:function(){
        this.getData()
        .done(function(result){
            console.log(result.length);
        })
        .fail(function(x){
            console.log(x);
        });
    },
    ....
}
```

I may not being fully understanding asyc behavior here. What I would have liked to do is get the result from `getData` and populate an object full of data that would be called whenever the user changes the view. From all I've read, thats not what promises are used for. Instead I should be returning a promise and using that data again? (Maybe this is my error of thought)

So my question is, once the data from `getData` is returned from AJAX, is there a way to return the promise and use the `.done` multiple times without hitting the server ever time? Meaning, since I will be using that same data and I can't save it to a global object, how could I achieve this?

Comment: You need to implement a method that 1) if it has the data stored somewhere, returns a promise of this data, 2) if it doesn't have data, it fetches it from server, returns a promise, and stores data in some private variable for subsequent calls (case 1)

Comment: If you're doing something like an auto complete search that continuously calls a server which may receive responses not in order, use `observables` instead. They're like promises but allows you to pick and choose your responses, discarding older ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the promise returned by `$.ajax()`. This makes the call only once (in the constructor) regardless of how often you call `getData()`:

```
function FeedData() {
    this.data_promise = $.ajax({
        url: 'php/getData.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {}
    });
}

FeedData.prototype = {
    constructor: FeedData,
    getData: function () {
        return this.data_promise;
    }
}

var feed = new FeedData();
feed.getData().then(function () {
    /* .. */
});
```

You can also delay fetching until you call `getData()` for the first time:

```
function FeedData() {
    this.data_promise = null;
}

FeedData.prototype = {
    constructor: FeedData,
    getData: function () {
        if (this.data_promise === null) {
            this.data_promise = $.ajax({
                url: 'php/getData.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {}
            });
        }
        return this.data_promise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the first example call `$.ajax()` again?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm not sure what you mean. It only gets called once, in the constructor. If you make two instances of `FeedData` it gets called twice.

Comment: Nice clean answer - what is the purpose of `constructor: FeedData` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not sure, I've never seen this form yet. I guess it's OPs preferred form of making classes.

Comment: oops, didn't see it in the question! I think it's redundant - given [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Comment: Well, I'd just use es6 `class` now so prototype is redundant for most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Note, `jQuery.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object.

At first successful `$.ajax()` call define a property to store the data at the instance. When `.then()` is called assign the result of `$.ajax()` to the value of the property at the object as a resolved `Promise`.

Retrieve the value from the object using `instance.property.then()`.

```
function feedData(arr) {
  var feed = this;
  this.getData = function() {
    return $.ajax({
           url: 'php/getData.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
                //data being sent over
           },
            // set `context` : `this` of `$.ajax()` to current `fedData` instance
           context: feed
        });
  };
  this.initData = function() {
    // note `return`
    return this.getData()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.length);
        // define `this.promise` as a `Promise` having value `result`
        this.promise = Promise.resolve(result);
        return result;
      })
      .fail(function(x) {
        console.log(x);
      });
  }
}

var request = new feedData();
request.initData().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});

// this will not make antoher request
request.promise.then(function(res) {     
  console.log("result:", res)
});
```

```js
function feedData(arr) {
  var feed = this;
  this.getData = function() {
    // do asynchronous stuff; e.g., `$.ajax()`
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
      dfd.resolveWith(feed, [
        [1, 2, 3]
      ])
    });
  };
  this.initData = function() {
    // note `return`
    return this.getData()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.length);
        // define `this.promise` as a `Promise` having value `result`
        this.promise = Promise.resolve(result);
        return result;
      })
      .fail(function(x) {
        console.log(x);
      });
  }
}

var request = new feedData();
request.initData().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
// this will not make another request
request.promise.then(function(res) {      
  console.log("result:", res)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, so could I wrap the bottom part in a function to be called anytime a users switches the views? and if so, this wont shot off another request to the server for the data?

Comment: Call `instance.promise.then(function(res) {})` to return saved `Promise` without making an `$.ajax()` call after initialization.